# Over exposure of hibernate pojo

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, dto

Well I have recently started reading up on Hibernate so my knowledge is very raw. 
I read somewhere that you should not expose your hibernate pojo classes directly on your application rather you should create classes which represents Pojo classes on your application. It's like custom classes which use only some or all of the fields of the Pojo classes.

Can someone put some light onto this as to how in an application we can stop the over exposure of Pojos or what is the correct way of using Pojos and custom classes which are returned from the server.

Comment: Sounds like what you are referring to is the DTO "Pattern". http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171457/what-is-the-point-of-using-dto-data-transfer-objects

Comment: yeah its some what similar to that. But my question is, Is that bifurcation necessary? can't we use pojo's directly on to the client.

Comment: Well, you'll find many discussions on that and will have to make up your own mind. My preferences is to use Entities as 'proper' domain objects: that fact they just happen to be persistent is neither here nor there. In my experience DTOs lead to -http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html  - neither the Entity or the DTO will have any behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Better you right your own POJOs classes with required fields... And also write translators to translate data from hibernate POJOS to you Pojos.

Note:- If you are evaluating Hibernate for something, have a look on **JOOQ**.....

Tomorrow is a world with out ORMss........

http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.6/manual-single-page/

Comment: That is an opinion rather than an answer. You could try qualifying it with what you would consider to be perceived benefits of this approach given the overhead of having to create and maintain not only the DTOs but also the mappers..

Comment: @Alan Hay
That's only my suggestion boss.. I only asked him to have a look on JOOQ. The freedom and flexiblity which we are getting through JOOQ like technology is not in Hibernates..... Even after Java 8 streams... do you still  believe ORM tools have place...?

Answer (score 0):

In general, I'd say it depends on your needs, but if you want to do it right, I suggest you have create custom classes for your DTOs that contain just the information you need. I have written an [article](https://blazebit.com/blog/2016/getting-started-with-blaze-persistence-entity-views.html) about why using entities might lead to problems and how you can implement DTOs with Blaze-Persistence Entity Views to solve your problems. That might help you a bit to understand the implications.